# Manually add providers for jaxb in a resteasy application

Tags: rest, jaxb, jax-rs, resteasy, undertow

I have a rest application where I am using resteasy and jaxb to produce json output

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Path("/data")
public MyResponse getData {
    return new MyResponse("my response"); // Just stubbing this
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "response")
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class MyResponse {
    private String data;

    public MyResponse(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

I am not using the web.xml but creating a RestApplication which extends Application and overriding the getSingletons and getClasses method.

Now I am not sure which jaxb provider classes I need to add to make the above working, I mean to do the json serialization.

I get the following error

```
Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type:MyResponse of media type: application/json
```

Could you let me know which  classes I need to add manually(the providers) to make this work?

Comment: Add manually? You mean no Maven/Gradle? Or do you mean register manually? If you have the dependencies, it should work out the box (without having to register anything). So I'm thinking you don't have the dependencies

Comment: Actually I take that back. Since you overrode the methods in the Application class to register your resources, it may not work out of the box. In which case, if you do have the required dependency, you will need to register the JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.

Comment: @peeskillet. That fixed it. Thanks a lot